# How to Join to a table where the result can sometimes lead with a - sign?

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc, openedge, progress-db

Hopefully i can explain this well enough. I have a bit of a unique issue where the customer system we use can change a ID in the database in the background based on the products status.

What this means is when i want to report old products we don't use anymore along side active products there ID differs between the two key tables depending on there status. This means Active products in the product table match that of the stock item table with both showing as `647107376` but when the product is no long active the `StockItem` table will present as `647107376` but the table that holds the product information the id presents as `-647107376`

This is proving problematic for me when i comes to joining the tables together to get the information needed. Originally i had my query set up like this:

```
SELECT

Company_0.CoaCompanyName
,SopProduct_0.SopStiStockItemCode AS hbpref
,SopProduct_0.SopStiCustomerStockCode AS itemref
,SopProduct_0.SopDescription AS ldesc
,StockMovement_0.StmOriginatingEntityID AS Goodsin

FROM 
SBS.PUB.StockItem StockItem_0 
LEFT JOIN SBS.PUB.SopProduct SopProduct_0 ON StockItem_0.StockItemID = SopProduct_0.StockItemID
LEFT JOIN SBS.PUB.Company Company_0 ON SopProduct_0.CompanyID = Company_0.CompanyID
LEFT JOIN SBS.PUB.StockMovement StockMovement_0 ON StockItem_0.StockItemID = StockMovement_0.StockItemID

WHERE 

Company_0.CoaCompanyName = ?
AND StockMovement_0.MovementTypeID = '173355'
AND StockMovement_0.StmMovementDate >= ? AND StockMovement_0.StmMovementDate <= ?
AND StockMovement_0.StmQty <> 0
AND StockMovement_0.StockTypeID ='12049886'
```

Unfortunately though what this means is any of the old product will not show because there is no matching id due to the `SopProduct` table presenting the `StockItemID` with a leading `-`

So from this i thought best to use a `case when` statement with a nested `concat` and `left` in it to bring through the results but this doesn't appear to work either sample of the join below:

```
LEFT JOIN SBS.PUB.SopProduct SopProduct_0 ON (CASE WHEN LEFT(SopProduct_0.StockItemID,1) = "-" THEN CONCAT("-",StockItem_0.StockItemID) ELSE StockItem_0.StockItemID END) = SopProduct_0.StockItemID
```

Can anyone else think of a way around this issue? I am working with a Progress OpenEdge ODBC.

Comment: What is the datatype of `StockItemID`, is it a string or a number?

Comment: @GMB its a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers look like numbers.  If they are, you can use `abs()`:

```
ON StockItem_0.StockItemID = ABS(SopProduct_0.StockItemID)
```

Otherwise a relatively simple method is:

```
ON StockItem_0.StockItemID IN (SopProduct_0.StockItemID, CONCAT('-', SopProduct_0.StockItemID))
```

Note that non-equality conditions often slow down `JOIN` operations.

Comment: ON StockItem_0.StockItemID = ABS(SopProduct_0.StockItemID) worked thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using an `or` in the join should work:

```
LEFT JOIN SBS.PUB.SopProduct SopProduct_0 
   ON SopProduct_0.StockItemID = StockItem_0.StockItemID
      OR
      SopProduct_0.StockItemID = CONCAT("-", StockItem_0.StockItemID)
```

You might need to `cast` the result of the `concat` to a number (if the ids are stored as numbers).

Or you could use the `abs` function too (assuming the ids are numbers):

```
LEFT JOIN SBS.PUB.SopProduct SopProduct_0 
   ON SopProduct_0.StockItemID = abs(StockItem_0.StockItemID)
```

Comment: ON StockItem_0.StockItemID = ABS(SopProduct_0.StockItemID) worked thank you